# Heartless bunch of faces

Tags: riddle, story

> I was having snacks with a friend the other day, i had pretzels and
>   my friend was licking candy canes when he told me a weird story. He
>   said that, the night before he was at a party at some rich guy's
>   house, where he saw 24 faces at a table, some men , a few women, but
>   apparently there were only 13 hearts at the table. After a while my
>   friend said since i had pretzels he is going to pay up the bills. I was a little surprised, as he usually never pays. Now what did my friend see the night before and why did he pay?

Comment: Could the downvoter kindly suggest me some improvement, so i can make it better.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you were

> playing cards.

24 faces

> 12 face cards in a deck, each with two faces

13 hearts

> in a deck

pretzels

> poker jargon for a pair of eights

candy canes

> poker jargon for a pair of sevens

he paid because

> you had a better hand.

Comment: And you take away the cake